# Smaller Resolution, Content Tries To Fit

Tags: css, xhtml, position, overflow, resolution

If you will notice when you visit... http://www.thebattleforarcadia.com/construction/index.html when you shrink the size of the screen the top bar content overflows it's parent div and runs over the rest of the website.

What I want to do is, if in-case the resolution of the receiving end is too small, I want to force them to have to use the scrollbar at the bottom so they can see everything. Just so the website is displayed properly.

Any coding ideas?

Thank you,
Aaron

Comment: What browser is this happening in? I don't see it...

Comment: Normally overflow property is used for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add...

```
min-width: 1260px;
```

at the
    #news-container
css rule.

Your website will display fine in 1280x**** resolutions but there will be a vertical scrollbar in anything less than that (in width).

Perhaps you could make the min-width 960px and make the text expand in two lines (pushing the top graphic a bit) ? Just a suggestion

EDIT: here's an example

```
#news-content {
float: left;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-top: 12px;
overflow: auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#news-container {
width: 100%;
background: url(images/news-background.png) repeat-x left bottom;
z-index: 10;
}
#news-header {
width: 150px;
height: 23px;
float: left;
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

The above example will make the header "Expand" when the resolution is shrinked without forcing screenwidth < 1280px users to use the vertical scrollbar

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, I applied that change to the #news-container, but it looked odd once I shrunk it to very small dimensions. So what I did was also applied the min-width: 1260px; to the body tag. And now it works/looks great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Give the `body` element or any other element that is setting the width you want a `min-width` to match that. This should make sure that whenever the page is being viewed on a smaller resolution have a horizontal scroll-bar

See here for [Commonly used pixel sizes for webpages and their pros/cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832609/commonly-used-pixel-sizes-for-webpages-and-their-pros-cons).

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to implement this answer with the answer below.